# Named v unnamed data type arguments

Tags: idris

In code from Chapter 6 of [Type Driven Development with Idris](https://www.manning.com/books/type-driven-development-with-idris), I was puzzled by this code:

```
data DataStore : Type -> Type where
    MkData : (size : Nat) ->
             (items : Vect size schema) ->
             DataStore schema
```

I thought it might not compile because `schema` seems to be undefined or at the very least needs to be somehow tied to the first parameter of `DataStore`. However, it loads fine and can be used like so:

```
*DataStore> the (DataStore String) $ MkData 2 ["Fred", "Wilma"]
MkData 2 ["Fred", "Wilma"] : DataStore String
```

I thought that the first argument to `DataStore` would need to be named `schema` like so:

```
data DataStore : (schema : Type) -> Type where
    MkData : (size : Nat) ->
             (items : Vect size schema) ->
             DataStore schema
```

This definition can be use similarly to the initial one.

I'm wondering if there is any semantic difference between the two definitions and if anyone can help me with my incorrect intuition about `schema` not being defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There're two things going on here. The first is implicit arguments. A lower case name used as an argument to a function is always converted to an implicit argument. For instance, the function composition operator:

```
Idris> :t (.)
(.) : (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
Idris> :set showimplicits 
Idris> :t (.)
Prelude.Basics.(.) : {c : Type} -> {a : Type} -> {b : Type} -> (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

The type of compose involves the variables a, b, and c which aren't declared anywhere in its type signature. Idris makes them into implicit arguments - all of which have type `Type` - which it will try to infer by unification. The `{curly brackets}` are the syntax for explicitly specifying an implicit argument. You can always use `:set showimplicits` in the interpreter to see them. In the `DataStore` example, `schema` is an implicit variable.

You can also specify implicits when you call functions that have them:

```
λΠ> MkData {schema = String} 2 ["hi", "Steven"]
MkData 2 ["hi", "Steven"] : DataStore String
```

The second thing is that variables in the type of the type constructor in a `data` declaration don't scope over anything but that type constructor. The second definition of `DataStore` you give is exactly equivalent to the original because the "schema" in `DataStore : (schema : Type) -> Type` isn't in scope in the type signature for `MkData`.

Comment: Good to know that "variables in the type of the type constructor in a data declaration don't scope over anything but that type constructor"! I wonder where did you learned that. Idris, to me sounds an even-better Haskell in terms of syntax, but systematic documentation seems inadequate...